# xslt 2.0 replace with xml-structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using xslt 2.0 and the replace-function. My task is to replace a part of a string with structure.
Example

Input:

```
<xml>
<content>Title 1: This will be on a new line</content>
</xml>
```

Output:

```
<xml>
<content>Title 1:</content><content>This will be on a new line</content>
</xml>
```

According to xslt 2.0 I am not allowed to have < or > in the replace string.
And if I use < or > that is being output as well...

xslt I am using is sort of like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(.*)\s+(.*)', $1</content><content>$2"/>
```

Comment: This is a task for `xsl:analyze-string`, not `replace()`.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I have written my solution below. tried to reference you in some way, but it didn't seem to do it correctly .... Again: Much appreciated with the suggestion you pointed me in direction of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^\D*\d+:\s+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <content>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </content>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <content>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </content>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1b5/1

Comment: See my comment below regarding my solution. Although not perfect, it did solve my problem and it was thanks to you suggestion on using analyze-string rather than replace.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [comment from michael-hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176556/xslt-2-0-replace-with-xml-structure/69177213#comment122265674_69176556) I was able to solve this problem.
I had to do some tweaks, but it did work.

Here is the solution:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(.*)(\d+)\s+(.*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="ELEMENT_CONTENT_END"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="ELEMENT_BR"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="ELEMENT_CONTENT_START"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
```

ELEMENT_CONTENT_START and ELEMENT_CONTENT_START is defined as following:

```
<xsl:template name="ELEMENT_CONTENT_END">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/content&gt;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ELEMENT_CONTENT_START">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;content&gt;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

Thanks for the valuable suggestion, Michael!

Comment: No, no, no! Do NOT use escaped text to create markup! Create the necessary elements directly using literal result elements.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would have done what you suggest (which is why I am tagging it as a correct answer. Unfortunately I have a rather complex system that I have inherited and thus I had to be creative. the sample I have provided is not nearly as complex as the one I am working on. You may also see that it starts with closing an element before starting a new one.